# javascript prime number query

Tags: javascript, numbers

this is my code :

```js
  var num = parseInt(105);
  // debugger
  if (num < 1) {
    console.log("=> 0 or minus value is not a prime number", num);


  } else if (num == 2) {
    console.log("=> 2 is a prime number", num);


  } else if (num > 2) {

    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        console.log("this is a not prime number as it is devided by zero");
        break


      } else {
        console.log("this is a prime number")

      }
    }
  }
```

in this code why else statement is showing the output when I put any odd numbers where I already worte the break statement for stopping the loop break.

Comment: This is your problem: `num % i == 0`. You are using the modulus on `i`. So basically you are looping: `105 % 2 > 105 % 3 > 105 % 4` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is not divisible by a particular `i` then your else condition is being executed. Change `num` to `5` you would see `this is a prime number` print several times.

You can create a function (as shown below) where we first check all the `i`s then print `this is a prime number`.

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  if (num < 1) {
    console.log("=> 0 or negative values are not prime numbers", num);
  } else if (num === 2) {
    console.log("=> 2 is a prime number", num);
  } else if (num > 2) {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
        console.log(`this is a not prime number as it is divisible by ${i}`);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("this is a prime number");
}

isPrime(105);
```

Or you can store the result in a variable, and at the end of the loop print `this is a prime number` if the variable wasn't set.

```js
const num = 105;
if (num < 1) {
  console.log("=> 0 or negative values are not prime numbers", num);
} else if (num === 2) {
  console.log("=> 2 is a prime number", num);
} else if (num > 2) {
  let isPrime;
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      console.log(`this is a not prime number as it is divisible by ${i}`);
      isPrime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isPrime !== false) {
    console.log("this is a prime number");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. another query hitting up on my mind. if I want to collect all the divisors then what should I do sir?